# Difference between bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo version and bitcoind --version

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

I tried to upgrade bitcoin core from 0.18.0 to 0.20.0.

When I ask for the version through bitcoind `bitcoind --version` it prints `Bitcoin Core version v0.20.0` but if I ask for the version through bitcoin-cli `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo` it prints `"subversion": "/Satoshi:0.18.0/"`

How is this possible that this is not the same?

Answer (score 3):

- `bitcoind --version` is asking the `bitcoind` binary what its version is
- `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo` asks the currently *running* `bitcoind` what its version is

So this means that you at some point had a 0.18.0 `bitcoind`, started it, then installed a 0.20.0 one, but the 0.18.0 one is still running.